# Insert a link with property into bindpopup polygon leaflet to open in new tab

Tags: javascript, leaflet

Can I insert a link into popup content on leaflet, like this

```
function onEachFeature(feature, layer) {
  idLoDat = feature.properties.IDLo;
  layer.bindPopup("Company name: " + feature.properties.TenCty + 
                  "</br>Detail: <a href= 'index.php?id=feature.properties.IDLo'</a>");
};
```

I want to open a new tab with id = property on GeoJSON file. How can do that?

Comment: Hi, do you need help for the link part or for the target page part? Please make sure to ask 1 specific issue and make your question title and content consistent accordingly.

Comment: I have edit my question, I want to insert a link for the target page. Can you help me?

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you just need to use string concatenation again:

```js
function onEachFeature(feature, layer) {
  idLoDat = feature.properties.IDLo;
  layer.bindPopup("Company name: " + feature.properties.TenCty + 
                  "</br>Detail: <a href='index.php?id=" + idLoDat + "'</a>");
};
```